# How can I use Convert.ChangeType instead of DateTime.ParseExact?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm writing a parser class which parses a `string` to a `type` with customized format.

For example I want to use `Parse<DateTime>("20161018",typeof(DateTime),UnknownFormatProvider)` and It returns the parsed `DateTime`;

I know I can use `DateTime.ParseExact` for converting `string` with specific format to `DateTime` but for the mentioned reason I must use `Convert.ChangeType(object,Type,IFormatProvider)`.

Is there any way to create an `IFormatProvider` to use in `Convert.ChangeType(object,Type,IFormatProvider)` to do make it work just like `DateTime.ParseExact`?

> Edit: Maybe `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo` should work, but I
>   still don't know how to set it to work like `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture doesn't work for my question, I want to specify  format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to create an `IFormatProvider` to use in
>   `Convert.ChangeType(object,Type,IFormatProvider)` to do make it work
>   just like `DateTime.ParseExact`?

I don't think so.

Both `Convert.ChangeType(Object, TypeCode, IFormatProvider)` and `Convert.ChangeType(Object, Type, IFormatProvider)` overloads uses [`IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.todatetime) method under the hood for `TypeCode.DateTime` and `typeof(DateTime)` as a second parameters.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,206
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,325

This method explained as;

> Converts the value of this instance to an **equivalent** DateTime using
>   the specified culture-specific formatting information.

I think both those overloads *only* accepts standard date and time formats used by `IFormatProvider` parameter if those `object` as a first parameter is a `string`.

This means this method overloads do not accept *any* custom date and time strings for a first parameter.