# Why doesn't Convert.ChangeType(string) work with DateTimeOffset, when it works with DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion, datetimeoffset

This happens even when I provide the timezone.

```
var dateString = "2008-09-22T14:01:54.9571247Z";
var dateTime = Convert.ChangeType(dateString, typeof(DateTime));  // works
var dateTimeOffset = Convert.ChangeType(dateString, typeof(DateTimeOffset));  // throws InvalidCast exception
```

Why does this happen?

And what I am trying to do is implement a catch-all type converter on the fly with `Convert.ChangeType`. It works with other types (e.g. `float` <-> `int`, `string` -> `DateTime`) except `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Because DateTimeOffset does not implement IConvertible

Comment: You cannot convert a DateTime to a DateTimeOffset.  An offset is the difference between two objects.

Comment: @jdweng `An offset is the difference between two objects.` Are you thinking of `TimeSpan`? Or maybe confused by the name? A better type name may have been `DateTimeWithIncludedOffset`.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961968/how-can-i-use-convert-changetype-instead-of-datetime-parseexact

Comment: A lot of wrong information in this comment section...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.8) method, you'll see the following note:

> **Exceptions**
>   [InvalidCastException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidcastexception?view=netframework-4.8)
>   This conversion is not supported.
>   -or-
>   `value` is `null` and `conversionType` is a value type.
>   -or-
>   `value` does not implement the [IConvertible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=netframework-4.8) interface.

Since we know that `value` is not null and that `string` implements the `IConvertible` interface, then the only reason left is the first one:

> **This conversion is not supported.**

---

What we **can** do is first convert it to a `DateTime`, and then convert that to a `DateTimeOffset`. There is some documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset) that describes various methods to accomplish this, one of which is:

> *"You can also create a new DateTimeOffset value by assigning it a DateTime value"*

So we can just do:

```
DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = (DateTime) Convert.ChangeType(dateString, typeof(DateTime));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer with an explanation on why and a solution for my problem. Your solution will work, but I want to implement a catch-all type converter if possible. So it doesn't look like using `Convert.ChangeType` would be a preferred solution because I'd have to use the method twice depending on the type. I'm doing a bit of research on my own too, but it may not be possible.